# is it possible to copy the current state of the statechart from one agent to another?

Tags: anylogic, agent-based-modeling

I am trying to make a model to simulate the contagion of covid in public spaces using a mix between SEIR and pedestrian models.
In another question I asked to use a static population. They suggested that before deleting the agent a copy be saved in a list and after the first X agents have been generated I want the next agent generated by the pedSource to be one of the list.

Currently what I do is take a random agent from the list and if it is infected I send a message to the new agent so that it goes into the infected state. But by doing that I am resetting the timeout to recover every time an agent enters the zone that I am modeling.
this is the code that currently runs in the pedSource on exit:

```
if (personasEnCasa.size()+personasEnSuper.size() > poblacionMaxima){
    Persona p = randomFrom(personasEnCasa);
    if (p.statechart.getState() == Persona.Infeccioso){
        send("Contagiado", ped);
    };
    personasEnCasa.remove(p);
};
```

personasEnSuper is my population of Persona, personasEnCasa is my list of agents outside the zone and and poblacionMaxima is the maximum number of agents in the lista and the population

I would like to be able to copy the current statechart of the agent in the list to the agent that generates my pedSource. Or use something similar to a pedSource.inject () but inserting an agent from the list instead of a new one. But I did not know how to do it.

is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

your ped already exists and you don't need to copy it you can just move it to the flow like this, with pedWait being any pedestrian block that you want, so instead of `send("Contagiado", ped);` you would do `enter.take(ped);`

[image: ped flow]

but if you insist in using the send, then you can use branches on your statechart to define where this ped goes:

[image: branches]
you will need in this case before the send, use ped.infectious=true; and the condition in the branch would be infectious==true to move to the infectious state.

As a side note, instead of p.statechart.getState() == Persona.Infeccioso you should use `p.statechart.getState().equals(Persona.Infeccioso)`

use == only with primitives such as boolean, int and double, otherwise you are susceptible to errors that are very difficult to discover

Comment: I tried to make the first option you gave me, and i got this error
`Agent (Agent#102[root.pedGoToSalida]:null) can't be in several flowcharts at the time. At least two flowchart blocks are in conflict: root.enter and root.pedGoToSalida
java.lang.RuntimeException: root.personasEnCasa[37]:`
what I am doing with the pedSink is that when an agent enters, I save a copy in another pupulation from where I will get agents so that they can re-enter. I also tried to use the goToPopulation () command in the pedSink got deleted from all populations. Should I use another block instead of pedSink?

Comment: show your flowchart then, because that means that your agent is already on a block, so why not continuing a normal flowchart instead of all this parafernalia.